# Binding in expression

Tags: haskell

I am trying to on wheatear argument with file name is passed to either parse the file or read from standard input:

```
let formulae = fmap parseInput $ if isInputFile args then (hGetContents $ openFile (last args) ReadMode) else hGetContents stdin
```

but of course this error occurs:

```
formula-2-bdd.hs:89:79:
    Couldn't match expected type `Handle' with actual type `IO Handle'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `openFile (last args) ReadMode'
    In the expression: (hGetContents $ openFile (last args) ReadMode)
```

If I bind IO Handle first I can't decided according to `isInputFile args:

```
handle <- openFile (last args) ReadMode
formulae = fmap parseInput $ if isInputFile args then hGetContents handle else hGetContents stdin
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand what the actual problem with the original `let` expression is.

```
let formulae = fmap parseInput $ if isInputFile args 
                                 then (hGetContents $ openFile (last args) ReadMode)
                                 else hGetContents stdin
```

The problem is that `stdin` is a `Handle`, while the return value of `openFile` is an `IO Handle`. To handle (no pun intended) both cases with the same code, you need to promote `stdin` to an `IO Handle`.

```
let formulae = fmap parseInput $ if isInputFile args
                                 then (hGetContents $ openFile (last args) ReadMode)
                                 else (hGetContents (pure stdin))
```

This can be rewritten a little more simply calling `hGetContents` on the result of the `if` expression, rather than having the `if` expression return the result of `hGetContents`.

```
let formulae = do handle <- if isInputFile
                            then openFile (last args) ReadMode
                            else return stdin
                  data <- hGetContents handle
                  fmap parseInput data
```